# WCF and Custom Soap Authentication

Tags: wcf, authentication, soap

I am developing a server application using WCF to expose WebService endpoints for clients. I want to implement authentication through a simple custom provider that will use the username and password passed through the SOAP headers. I know how to set the user name and password to be sent on the client, I just want to know how to pull the username and password out of the SOAP header on the server side. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the username and password validator in the service behavior

```
<behavior name="MyServiceBehavior">
  <serviceCredentials>
    <userNameAuthentication userNamePasswordValidationMode="Custom"
      customUserNamePasswordValidatorType="MyNamespace.MyUserNamePasswordValidator, MyDll" />
  </serviceCredentials>
</behavior>
```

you can access the user name and password from  MyUserNamePasswordValidator  class

```
public class MyUserNamePasswordValidator : UserNamePasswordValidator
{
    public override void Validate( string userName, string password )
    {
        // valid your password here 
    }
}
```

Comment: I follow your tips but a can't get the method Validate called. I need send a UserName and Password without requiring HTTPS and without requiring a certificate installed on the server, using the basicHttpBinding.