# WCF Emulate the Salesforce.com login service

Tags: wcf, binding, token, salesforce

How would I accomplish what Salesforce.com does for logging in with WCF? I would like to have an authentication service that returns a token on a correct login. Then, each set of service calls would pass the token back. I don't want to pass the token on each method call.

What is throwing me is how the session header is part of the binding.

I am also looking for why this is or isn't a good idea. I think it is clean and simple.

Thanks!

```
 // Create service object   

  binding = new SforceService(); 
  // Invoke the login call and save results in LoginResult   

  LoginResult lr = binding.login("username","password"); 
  if (!lr.passwordExpired) {
  // Reset the SOAP endpoint to the returned server URL   

  binding.Url = lr.serverUrl; 
  // Create a new session header object   

  // Add the session ID returned from the login   

  binding.SessionHeaderValue = new SessionHeader(); 
  binding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId = lr.sessionId; 
  GetUserInfoResult userInfo = lr.userInfo; 
  } else {
    Console.WriteLine("Your password is expired.");
  }
```

Comment: It sounds like you are looking to add a custom SOAP header... I've done this in .NET using a System.Web.Services.WebService, and would be shocked if there wasn't a way to do it in WCF.  This question looks similar and has an accepted response: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/321764/wcf-and-custom-soap-authentication

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking to leverage the [Windows Identity Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/security/aa570351.aspx) and it's Security Token Service / STS model.

Comment: Chris, I am not concerned about providing the token as much as I am trying to use it. I don't understand how to attach it to the binding like SalesForce does or how to pull it out in the service.

Comment: If you use WIF you would have all of that baked in, if you wish to implement it all yourself all you need to do is pass around the token in a session cookie and then validate the cookie on each request.

Comment: Thanks Chris, I was hoping to to do it without cookies right on the binding. What happens if the client consuming the service is not .Net?

Comment: Even if the client isn't .NET they should still be able to handle passing the cookie across the wire otherwise that sounds like a shortcoming of the client.